# Access local resources with hazelcast scheduled job

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm very new to Hazelcast, and it might very well be that I am missing something glaringly obvious, but here goes.
I have a Java Application that runs distributed, each containing its own Hazelcast Instance. I need Hazelcast to schedule a job that will run at a fixed rate, but never simultaneously on several instances. To achieve this I plan to use the IScheduledExecutorService and create a job that implements Runnable and NamedTask.
My problem is that the job needs to call methods on the application. My understanding is that the job is serialized and deserialized by hazelcast, which means that I can't just create a Runnable and feed it the objects it needs through its constructor. So how do I "Get back" to the application objects from the Hazelcast job?

For example, say I had a plain old java Runnable that i would like to execute in a Hazelcast Executor like this:

```
public class DoStuffJob implements Runnable, NamedTask {
    private MyResource resource;
    
    public DoStuffJob (MyResource resource){
        this.resource = resource;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Do stuff";
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        resource.doAllTheStuff();
    }
    
}
```

How would I create a Runnable I can execute on Hazelcast, that can still access MyResource on the instance it executes on?

The only option I have found is to make the job HazelcastInstanceAware, and use the HazelcastInstance.getUserContext() to keep the object, but I am hoping it is somehow possible to "get back" to the executing application.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your Runnable task put the derived data into a distributed data-structure - probably an IMap. It would then be accessible from any of your JVMs. Would that handle your requirements?